# Sending data to remote servers with python

Tags: python, http, sockets, networking, ftp

We are building an in house software package that will exclusively be used on Verizon aircards. We want a simple way to send data from the laptop to our servers. Originally we were going to use python and FTP but found out that Verizon's ToS sometimes block ftp access. Our next idea was to use port 80 to send files. How could I achieve this with python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python has http client libraries -- you can easily use those to post data to a web server. Read up on the documentation for the python core libraries.

Comment: What do you mean by "remotely"?

Comment: Without connected over vpn. Also how do I actually read the file to the server.

Comment: It has nothing to do with vpns. (Nor, for that matter, does this have anything to do with Verizon aircards or the like.)

If you have a web server, and you have appropriately set up a page on it to accept data via http's "post" method, you can use a python script to send data to it, just as you would have used python to ftp a file to an ftp server.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the ftp port to 80. Some rules only block the ftp port (21)
And for python to use socket, here is the webpage 
http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html